# How to convert list of pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp to datetime.datetime?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a list `panndas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`.
I need to convert this to `datetime.datetime` of `pandas.core.series.Series`
`to_pydatetime()` is working for 1 row but not whole column.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"year": [2015, 2016], 
                    "month": [2, 3], 
                    "day": [4, 5], 
                    "hour": [2, 3]})

df=pd.to_datetime(df)
type(df.loc[0])
```

Out: `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`

I want to change DF to datetime.datetime of of pandas.core.series.Series
my desired output is as below

```py
df
```

Out:

```
0 2015-02-04 02:00:00
1 2016-03-05 03:00:00
```

```py
df.loc[0]
```

out: `datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 4, 2, 0)`

```
df.loc[1]
```

out: `datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 5, 3, 0)`

My question above may look strange as I start from Dataframe and changed to `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp` and trying to go back to Dataframe.
However, I used this code just as example.
What I actually have is dataframe imported from excel file and did computation using `pandas.tseries` and finally got `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`.
I need to convert this to datetime.datetime. I couldn't post all my excel files and others.
So I took above code as example.

Comment: When I run this above dataframe constructor, I do get the desired pd.Series in pandas 1.3.2.  Well, I do get the times too not just the dates as you've listed here.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You get a Series of `datetime64[ns]` from `pd.to_datetime` why do you need `datetime.datetime`? This code seems to be the exact sample example from [What's new v0.18.1 (May 3, 2016)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.18.1.html#whatsnew-0181-enhancements-assembling) unveiling `to_datetime`'s ability to process a DataFrame as input

Comment: I edited my question in order to make my intention clearer.

Comment: [pd.Series.dt.to_pydatetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_pydatetime.html) - is this what you're looking for?

Comment: df.dt.to_pydatetime() generates numpy.ndarry although format is datetime.datetime.  What I need is datetime.datetime of pandas.core.series.Series. Can you help further?

Comment: what is "datetime.datetime of pandas.core.series.Series" supposed to be? Do you mean a Python list? *Why* do you need native Python datetime class objects anyway, for what? If you're working with pandas, generally you'll want (Series of) pandas datetime datatype as it offers much more functionality as e.g. the `dt` accessor